# Convert columns to rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this

```
A              B              C              D              E
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mercedes       A Class        C Class        E Class        G Wagon
BMW            1 Series       3 Series       4 Series
```

and I wish to create a spreadsheet that looks like this

```
A              B
------------------------------
Merecedes       A class
Merecedes       C class
Merecedes       E class
Merecedes       G Wagon
BMW             1 Series
BMW             3 Series
BMW             4 Series
```

I have used the transpose function, but it doesn't create a new record for each value, but rather just rearranges the columns.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: Are you product agnostic or limited to Google sheets?

Comment: I would prefer Google Sheets, but I'm open to Excel

Comment: You could do this in python, I usually get data like this and I often have to melt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of anyone who's search brought them to this old question on this perennial need; this type of rearranging is a bit easier than it used to be, with Google's addition of the [`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) function. Example formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"|"&B2:E),"|"),"select * where Col2 is not null"))
```

From the inside out, here we work on a temporary array of makes and models,
with a symbol `|` concatenated between makes from `A` and models found in `B:E`,
`FLATTEN` then puts it all into a single column,
then `SPLIT` uses the temporary `|` characters to split it to a two-column array,
and finally, a quick  `QUERY` lets us filter out blanks after the fact (like the row `E3` would become), without having to do all the calculations twice.
Oh, and `ARRAYFORMULA` lets it work across the whole array of makes and models we input.

[image: Screenshot of the above formula in operation on the example data from the original question.]

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking for this same answer.
What you are trying to do it called unpivoting but it doesn't look like there is a built in function in google sheets to do it.

I found this fix in the google product forums. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/5UAxnQKMFm8

At first glance it looks a little complicated but victor tabori's code worked like a charm.

copy and paste his code into tools script editor in your google sheet and then use the =unpivot function in your spreadsheet.  Only limitation I ran into was it failed trying to reference data in a different page of the sheet.